# How to autolayout in Xcode buttons filled with different sized images?

Tags: uibutton, uiimage, autolayout, constraints, xcode7

I am working on a project with multiple buttons on a viewcontroller and I used autolayout. I want all the buttons to have equal widths and heights and I have horizontal/vertical spacing like this:

[image: add new constraints]

The result on multiple devices is like this:

[image: preview of multiple devices]

For the example I gave the buttons a background color, but in fact they will be filled with images of all kinds of sizes. I have image assets (@1x/@2x/@3x) for the buttons. For example, the @2x image assets will never be bigger then 100width and 75height (points).

Some of the button images can be changed by the user. So I want the button size to be ‘independent’  of the images inside. The buttons should NOT resize based on the image ‘inside’.

So I want to first(auto)layout the buttons, without the images ‘filling’ the buttons, so that the buttons will have the optimum size for the biggest sized images in my project (for the @2x image assets as mentioned:100width&75height points).

When I autolayout the buttons, and afterwards fill them with the images, xcode ‘wants’ to let me update the frames because of misplaced views. I do NOT want the images affecting the autolayout.

If I just run the app on the simulator or on a real iphone, it runs fine. But I have all these misplaced views warnings. What should I do? How will I 'tell' Xcode(7.1) that the images should NOT affect the width and heights of the buttons?

I have the feeling I have a slightly wrong approach to this (auto)layout problem, but I can not yet put my finger on it. I think I make some kind of logical error.

Is it good practice to first (auto)layout the buttons and then ‘fill’ with the images? Or should I fill the buttons with the images and then (auto)layout?
 Here an example with images which are of equal widths and heights:
[image: example with images]

Regarding the earlier question about conflicting constraint:

So I want these buttons to have equal width and heights: ideally 100width and 75height in points. The width will be alright, but the heights is somewhat difficult when I am using autolayout for different sized viewcontrollers (with a scrollview on it). I want to use additional constraints that 'says'; the buttons should NOT have a height value lower then 75 points. If I use a fixed height constraint, with 'equal or higher then' 75 points I get a conflict with the equal heights constraints (off course). I guess I should work with priorities, but I tried, and I did NOT succeed yet with it.

How should I proceed?

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

#### Question 1:

Of course you're getting a conflict when setting two height constraints of which one computes to 1/3 of the screen width (≈ 107px excluding padding on the iPhone 4) and the other enforces a minimum height that is bigger than this value (e.g. 120px).

Fortunately there's a way out of this using **priorities**:

Set the fixed height constraint's priority to a value below the priority of your 'greater or equal' constraint. This way autolayout will choose the fixed height constraint only if its constant is greater or equal to the constant of your 'greater or equal' constraint. Otherwise the constant of your 'greater or equal' constraint will be used as the view's height. Makes sense, right? :)

#### Question 2:

You can achieve the desired behavior as described in your second question by enforcing a fixed height and width for your image view and setting its content mode to "Aspect Fit". In Interface Builder there's a drop down menu for that:

[image: Image Content Mode]

In your case the best way to give the image view fixed dimensions is to pin all four sides to its superview (because the superview has a well-defined size):

[image: Image View with constraints]

So when you apply these leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints to all your image views the images will automatically resized according to the constraints and the result will look like this:

[image: Three image views in a row with constraints]

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. It is almost the answer I need, but not exactly what I was after. That is because I stated my questions poorly. So I will update/edit my questions accordingly (tomorrow). Thanks in advance for looking at my updated questions!

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem yet?

Comment: Thanks for asking! The last couple of days I am trying to update my skills and knowledge of autolayout. I have updated my question, hoping it clears up what it is that I want. I still fear it will be a little bit confusing, to know exactly what I mean. If needed, I will provide additional information

Comment: Great! I'll see if I can come up with a solution tonight... :)